# I cant get my ios custom urlscheme to work with numbers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

If I use for example

`seveneleven://` it works

if I use

`711://` it fails or

`7eleven://` it fails

I searched the web and found no results for this same issue. Am I the first one or is it just understood secretly that u cant use url schemes that start with numbers?

Comment: no you can cant use url schemes that start with numbers. i have cheked out.

Comment: can you give a link to where this information is confirmed? If you do and respond as an answer i'll up vote you.

Comment: i given below a link in answere by me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of what is a valid scheme name may be found on: http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt under "BNF for specific URL schemes". For "scheme" it states:

`scheme                  ialpha
ialpha                  alpha [ xalphas ]
alpha                   a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j | k |
                        l | m | n | o  | p | q | r | s | t | u | v |
                        w | x | y | z | A | B | C  | D | E | F | G |
                        H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P |  Q | R |
                        S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z
xalpha                  alpha | digit | safe | extra | escape`

See the page for full definition.

This means that a scheme may not start with a digit (or any other non-alpha)